# how to update list box using separate python module

Tags: python, tkinter, python-multithreading

i want to update list box in GUI.py using separate python module

I tried it with this code

**GUI.py**

```
class Window:


    def __init__(self,root,li) -> None:
        self.li = li
        self.root = root

    def main(self):

        self.root.geometry("609x96+951+216")
        self.root.minsize(120, 1)
        self.root.maxsize(2052, 1133)
        self.root.resizable(1,  1)


        listbox = Listbox(self.root)
        self.lb = listbox
        listbox.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)

        self.root.mainloop()    

    def insLi(self):

        if self.li != '':
            self.lb.selection_clear(0,END)
            self.lb.insert(END, self.li)
            self.lb.selection_set(END)
            self.lb.see(END)
            time.sleep(1)
```

**updater.py**

```
import GUI as sf


def processing_something():
    while True:
        print('processing something')
        time.sleep(1)
        
def popupmsg():
    root = Tk()
    window1 = sf.Window(root,'')
    t=th.Thread(target=window1.main)
    t.start()

popupmsg()
processing_something()
sf.window1.li='update me'
```

i got an error message

Exception has occurred: RuntimeError

main thread is not in main loop

How can I solve this?

Comment: Hi, at your GUI.py you have this line " listbox = Listbox(self.root)", what is a hint that you want to create a object of the class "Listbox". This class is never been defined. Same for root = Tk() in updater.py. Tk is not a defined class. You have to import it before you can use it.

Comment: It is better to run `processing_something()` in a child thread instead of `window1.main()`.